# {PHP} How can I update this ($plugin->release = '2.2.1'; )

Tags: php, moodle

Please help me
// This is the named version.How can i update this ($plugin->release = '2.2.1'; )

The steps ask me to update this version as shown in the picture, and this is the version code that is found on the PHP page

I didn't do anything

[image]

Comment: You didn't have to do anything: time passes, and your plugin(s) go out of date. Find out which plugin(s) this is for (only you can do this, by disabling all plugins and re-enabling them one by one until you get this error) and then update any that gets flagged as out of date.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the error message :)

`Debug info: Missing version.php file`

Your blocks/blocks plugin needs a `version.php` file

https://moodledev.io/docs/apis/plugintypes/blocks#versionphp

Something like this

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();

$plugin->version   = 2023061800;        // The current plugin version (Date: YYYYMMDDXX).
$plugin->requires  = 2011070110;        // Requires this Moodle version.
$plugin->component = 'block_blocks'; // Full name of the plugin (used for diagnostics)
```